# Wordpress Theme: Box jumping in chrome

Tags: css, wordpress

Hoping someone here can help me, I installed a wordpress theme on a site ( http://nationalaviationinstitute.ie/ ) and I have an issue I can't resolve and the developer of the theme is refusing to acknowlege the issue!

If you visit the above site in Chrome, the bottom section of the site jumps up and covers the four service areas underneath the image slider. This only happens in Chrome, it's ok in all other browsers, it's obviously something to with the responsiveness of the site as if you resize the bottom section moves back to the correct position.

I'm fairly familiar with CSS and HTML so if anyone could give me a hand figuring out the cause of this and a possible solution I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

Anthony

Comment: I see the site exactly the same on Firefox and on Chrome... What do you want to do with area below the slider???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a javascript bug which is giving the divs inside each `<li>` tag `style="height: 0px;"` on resize event like the example below:

```
<li class="span3 thumbnail">
    <div class="block-thumbnail maxheight col" style="height: 0px;"> 
        <i class="icon-3x icon-cogs"><i class="circle-border"></i></i>
        <h3>Our Courses</h3>
        <p>At NAI we have a number of different courses to suit everybody’s needs, academic to professional.  <a class="link" href="http://nationalaviationinstitute.ie/courses/">read more →</a></p>
    </div>
</li>
```

if you find and fix the js that is causing this problem than the problem will be fixed.

But incase you need a faster fix you can add the following css:

```
.block-thumbnail{
     display: inline-block;
}
```

It will override the `style="height: 0px;"` added by the js and the bottom section will be pushed down

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. You're a life saver. I've implemented the quick fix so I can demo the site, and I'll look at the more detailed fix later. Thanks again.

Comment: @ryanoryan You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem.

Comment: Upvoted due to being helpful.

On another note, this button is annoying:
a.btn-light.

Try adding a similar background to the blue.